# Why is onSubmitComplete() not executed after submitting FormPanel?

Tags: servlets, gwt

I have a form for submitting credit card information data:

```
<g:FormPanel ui:field="creditCardForm" action="/app/create-credit-card" method="post">
    <g:HTML>
        <input data-braintree-name="number" value="4111111111111111"/>
        <input data-braintree-name="cvv" value="100"/>

        <input data-braintree-name="expiration_date" value="10/20"/>

        <input data-braintree-name="postal_code" value="94107"/>
        <input data-braintree-name="cardholder_name" value="John Smith"/>
    </g:HTML>
   </g:FormPanel>
```

But for some reason the `SubmitCompleteHandler` does not come into action when the `POST` is done:

```
this.creditCardForm.addSubmitHandler(new SubmitHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onSubmit(SubmitEvent event) {
        LOGGER.fine("onSubmit()");
    }
});

this.creditCardForm.addSubmitCompleteHandler(new SubmitCompleteHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onSubmitComplete(SubmitCompleteEvent event) {
        LOGGER.fine("complete ..");
        LOGGER.fine("Submit result: " + event.getResults());
    }
});
```

The Servlet resturns just a `String` and writes some debug messages:

```
public class CreateCreditCardServlet extends HttpServlet implements Servlet {

    private final static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(CreateCreditCardServlet.class.getName());

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, java.io.IOException {          LOGGER.debug("#########################################################");
        LOGGER.debug("doPost");
        LOGGER.debug("#########################################################");
        resp.getOutputStream().println("This is servlet response");
    }
}
```

I see the response coming in the developer tool but why is the handler not getting called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [FormPanel](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FormPanel.html#FormPanel()) documentation:

> The back-end server is expected to respond with a content-type of
>   'text/html', meaning that the text returned will be treated as HTML.
>   If any other content-type is specified by the server, then the result
>   HTML sent in the onFormSubmit event will be unpredictable across
>   browsers, and the onSubmitComplete event may not fire at all.

So, in the servlet you need to do something like that:

```
resp.setContentType("text/html")
```